# how to pass variable value to SSIS package executed by a job via stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

Well yeah, pretty specific.
I have a job that executes a SSIS Package. This package has a variable called "Email" which is a string.

I'm executing this job via stored procedure. I need to pass the value for that variable to the job, how do I do it?

This is the stored procedure I'm using to execute the job (@VarValue is the value I want to pass to the SSIS package):

```
USE [DevDB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spChecklistEmail]
    @JobName [nvarchar](100),
    @VarValue [nvarchar](255),
    @ReturnValue [int] OUT
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @JobId binary(16);
    DECLARE @job_status INT

    SELECT @JobId = job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE (name = @JobName);
    SELECT @job_status = [dbo].[fn_GetJobStatus](@JobName);

    IF (@job_status IN (2, 4))
        BEGIN 
            SET @ReturnValue=@job_status;
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            IF (@JobId IS NOT NULL)
                BEGIN
                    EXEC @ReturnValue=msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_id=@JobId;
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @ReturnValue=-2;
                END
    END

    RETURN (@ReturnValue)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any real easy way to do this. The only thing I can think of is to take that value and before you call the package create a table or temp table and load the variable into that table you created. After that you could then access that varibale in you ssis package for what you need to use it for. Don't forget to clean up the extra table and/or value after the job.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj820152.aspx

Specifically part 2.

Looks like you can create variables and set them in the EXEC statement.

```
EXEC @ReturnValue=msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_id=@JobId, @parameter_name=N'Email', @parameter_value=@VarValue;
```

Something like that.

Comment: almost, but the sp_start_job SP doesnt accept anything other than @job_id